# Память JVM и анонимные строки

Tags: java, jvm, heap

Есть код:

```
String str = “text” + “second text”;
```

После выполнения кода переменная str будет ссылаться на строку, находящуюся в пуле строк. Будет ли создаваться в данном пуле ячейки для “text” и “second text” во время выполнения данной инструкции?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, уже компилятор сольет две константы и оставит одну строку. В байткоде уже будет эквивалент:

```
String str = "textsecond text";
```

Проверить это можно следующим образом. Скомпилируем код:

```
class Main {
    String str = "text" + "second text";
}
```

Потом выведем байткод с помощью команды `javap -c Main.class`:

```
Compiled from "Main.java"
class Main {
  java.lang.String str;

  Main();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: ldc           #2                  // String textsecond text
       7: putfield      #3                  // Field str:Ljava/lang/String;
      10: return
}
```

Видим константу `String textsecond text`

Comment: А если будет что-то типа: String str = “text”+str1+”text1”, где str1 переменная?

Comment: @JavaJunior Нет, так компилятор уже не умеет. Будут три разные строки. Можете поэкспериментировать сами. Способ я в ответе показал.